# Check if page current domain is of Community or normal domain

Tags: community, lightning-aura-components, url, custom-domain

I want to keep it simple and want to know if current page / app has been opened in Communities or opened in normal vf page or may be a part of lightning app?

Any idea around same?

Thanks,
Ray

Answer (score 1):

This may not be all-inclusive as I may have overlooked something, but it should give you a pretty good basis to build from.

From the [URL Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_url.htm%23apex_methods_system_url)

- `getSalesforceBaseUrl()`
  Returns the URL of the Salesforce instance.

From the [Network Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_network.htm%23apex_classes_network) for Communities:

- `public static String communitiesLanding()` 
  PageReference - If Communities isn’t enabled for the user’s organization or the user is currently in the internal organization, returns null.
- `public static String getNetworkId()` 
  If Communities isn’t enabled for the user’s organization or the user is currently in the internal organization, returns null.

**Note:** From within Visualforce there's also `$Network.Name` that can be used for some of this.

From the [Site Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm%23apex_classes_sites):

- `getBaseCustomUrl()`
  Returns a base URL for the current site that doesn’t use a Force.com subdomain.
- `getBaseInsecureUrl()`
  Returns a base URL for the current site that uses HTTP instead of HTTPS. The current request's domain is used. The returned value includes
  the path prefix and never ends with a / character. If the current request is not a site request, then this method returns an empty string.
- `getBaseSecureUrl()`
  Returns a base URL for the current site that uses HTTPS instead of HTTP. The current request's domain is preferred if it supports HTTPS.
  Domains that are not Force.com subdomains are preferred over Force.com subdomains. A Force.com subdomain, if associated with the
  site, is used if no other HTTPS domains exist in the current site. If no HTTPS custom URLs exist in the site, then this method returns an
  empty string. The returned value includes the path prefix and never ends with a / character. If the current request is not a site request,
  then this method returns an empty string.
- `getDomain()`
  Returns the Force.com domain name for your organization. (use for comparison)

**Note:** from within Visualforce, `$Site` Global Variable can be used to get the Force.com Domain and other variations on the above Controller methods. Commands like `$Site.BaseCustomUrl`, `$Site.BaseInsecureUrl`, `$Site.BaseSecureUrl`, `$Site.BaseUrl` and `$Site.Prefix` are the ones you'll want to look at using.